# How do I hook a WD Passport portable HD up to a docking station?

Tags: docking-station

The docking stations I have seen are USB to SATA. I would like to be able to plug my portable hard drives into it as well.

Comment: Why exactly are you unable to hook up the drive?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The fun/annoying thing with the WD passports is they have the USB/sata bridge built in with no easily accessible SATA connectors. You'd need to find a docking station that also includes, or simply use a USB hub instead.

Considering the whole point of a USB-Sata dock is the difficulty of plugging in an arbitrary sata drive to an arbitrary system externally, Its just not something they're designed to do